# Is creating asymmetric keys dynamically and storing in memory safe?

Tags: python, oauth2, jwt, asymmetric

I want to make an application that uses oauth2 and JWT as access tokens for securing some apis and providing authentication mechanisms. The application is a microservice architecture and wirtten in python. It would be deployed on AWS. So I have a authorization-service and an api-service. I want the auth-service to sign the tokens with a private key. But what is the safest way to distribute the public key to the api-service and how would I store the private key?

My idea was that the auth-service creates a key-pair and provides an endpoint that returns the actual public-key. With this I can rotate the key-pair and create for example every day (or hour?) a new key-pair. The private key would be stored in memory using the dict structure or whatever. The api-service would get a request with an access token and checks the signature with the public key returned by the auth-services endpoint. The reason for keeping the private key in memory is, that I wanted to create it dynamically at runtime and rotate it easily. **Is this a safe way or are there better ways of handling this kind of situation?**

My idea is based on some articles I read about key distribution and rotation but I am not sure if I got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon has a couple of services that target this kind of use-case.

[Amazon KMS](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/) is a key storage platform that integrates with AWS. You can upload keys to it and have your applications sign stuff via the [sign API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/APIReference/API_Sign.html). This keeps the actual keys off your servers. Another benefit is that it integrates with all of the security monitoring and alerting in the AWS ecosystem (e.g. GuardDuty) so you can catch potential compromises and misuse of those resources.

If you're solely using this for authentication, though, you might want to consider [Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) instead. It supports both OAuth2 and JWT. This saves you the effort and potential security pitfalls of implementing your own integration with KMS.

Regarding key rotation, that's not something you should need to worry about all that much for this use-case, and you definitely don't want to be rotating long-term OAuth or JWT keys on a daily (let alone hourly!) basis. From a cryptographic perspective there's no reason to rotate OAuth2 signing certificates any more frequently than once every few years, as long as you use sufficiently strong keys, just like you would with HTTPS. The usual justification for rotating keys more frequently than that is to minimise the attack window in case of key theft, but if you don't detect the breach then an attacker can simply quietly sit on the server and obtain the new keys every time they are rotated. Automated key rotation also introduces a greater attack surface due to the additional mechanisms required. A better approach is to use existing solutions that have been implemented by and tested by security professionals, spend your time understanding their security properties and controls, and focus on breach detection and monitoring of security-critical resources.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will definitely have a look at those 2 Services. The Microservices will be docker containers and deployed in a Cluster (I never worked with AWS so I dont know If they use kubernetes or have something of their own). Will that be a Problem when using cognito?